# Best practice to place scripts in partial view which is tightly bound to model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, model-binding

I have heard that we should not use scripts tag in partial view. 
But how could I avoid scripts in below partial view as scripts uses model of partial view?
Suggest me better approach.

```
@model AddressBookMVC.Models.Contact
<div class="contact-information">
  <ul
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="edit">EDIT</a>
        <a href="#" id="edit">DELETE</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
    <div id="name" class="detailed-contact">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div id="email" class="detailed-contact">
        Email:
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div>
        <span id="mobile" class="detailed-contact">
            Mobile:
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Mobile)
        </span>

    </div>

</div>
<script>
    $('#edit').on('click', function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EditContact", "Contacts")',
            type: 'get',

            //Here I am using model
            **data:{contactID:@Model.ContactID}**
        }).done(function(partialView)
        {
            $('#sidePanel').html(partialView);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your `#edit` markup contain the necessary url:

```
<div id="edit" data-url="@Url.Action("EditContact", "Contacts", new { contactID = Model.ContactID })">
    Click me for the fun stuff
</div>
```

and then all that's left to do in your separate javascript file included in your main layout is this:

```
$('#edit').on('click', function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
    }).done(function(partialView) {
        $('#sidePanel').html(partialView);
    })
});
```

As you can see your javascript no longer depends on any Model specific stuff - all it does is rely on what's already in the DOM. And what's already in the DOM is something that your partial view needs to take care of in order to include all the required details. So now you could move this javascript to a separate file and take advantage of things like js combination and minification. And of course your partials are absolutely free of any javascript.

Comment: I have made change like this. It is anything wrong to give data-url attribute to a tag because it already has href tag            <li >
            <a href="#" id="edit" data-url='@Url.Action("EditContact","Contacts", new { contactID=Model.ContactID})' >
EDIT</a>
</li>
        <li>

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I got this question because of your answer that I have seen.

Comment: I have tried to message you but stackoverflow dont have that option. Tried commenting your answer but couldnt as I dont have enough reputations to comment.

Comment: Normally for anchors you would use the `Html.ActionLink` helper and do not hardcode them as `<a>` tags like you have right now. So basically you could have this: `@Html.ActionLink("EDIT", "EditContact", "Contacts", new { contactID = Model.ContactID }, new { id = "edit" })`. And then inside your javascript just get the `href` tag of the anchor: `var url = $(this).attr('href');`. And also don't forget to cancel the default action of the anchor which will redirect to the server by returning `false` from your javascript on click callback at the end.

Comment: Ok, Darin. Thank you for taking time to suggest me.  But problem is I had to put image tag inside <a> tag. So I was not able to use html helper. Can you please suggest any alternate approach?